# How to solve scrolling failure in GIMP in Mojave

Tags: scrolling, gimp, macos-mojave, zoom

Whenever I make zoom in any image in GIMP and try to use scrolling, the image gets fragmented in rectangles, any ideas?

[image: Failure zoom and scrolling in GIMP IN MOJAVE]

Comment: Make sure you've got the latest video drivers installed. Also, what computer do you have?

Answer (score 0):

I manage to solve it installing macports and doing `sudo port install gimp`